# Pack PHP composer dependencies like webpack

Tags: php, laravel, dependencies, composer-php

Is it possible to pack PHP (Laravel/Lumen) composer dependencies like webpack does with Node?

Just a question, do you know a way?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean in a little more detail? What are you hoping to achieve with this? :)

Comment: Reduce the number of inodes in a server by packing dependencies (like 7000 files or more) into one per dependency (100 files more or less)

Comment: I think this would do the trick: https://github.com/mpyw/comphar